# Windows xcopy does not copy file back to directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

i have this script which i try to copy the file directory up using : "../"

```
del /f foo.zip
cd foo_directory
zip -r foo.zip *
xcopy foo.zip ../
cd ..
```

but i keep getting this error :

```
Does ../ specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? d
File creation error - Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Unable to create directory - C:\test\foo_paraent_dir\
0 File(s) copied
```

i just want to copy the zip to the directory above .

Comment: `xcopy foo.zip ..` works fine on Windows 7 and 10. Also note that the path separator on Windows is the backslash, not the forward slash.

Comment: In your open [tag:command-prompt] window, _([tag:cmd])_, type the following, `xcopy /?` and press the enter key. The usage information and options for [tag:xcopy] will be output for you to read, learn and implement.